# How is the inverter connected to the grid?

Tags: connector, inverter, power-engineering, power-grid, microgrid

I just finished circuit designing of an inverter which converts 440V DC to 230V AC. Now my manager asked me what kind of connectivity does it has.

I answered him:

"The current connectivity is AC as we have a DC/AC converter to connect to the grid".

He thought it was a stupid answer and he responded:
"Is this your engineering response? That the unit will connect to the AC?!"

I can see that he was mad by my answer but I told him what I knew. I have never worked in this field before and so I'm learning through this job.

Thiss made to do some research on type of connectivity from inverter to grid. All I see in the internet is much about type of coupling (AC coupling and DC coupling). I still didn't find how actually the inverter output is connected to the grid? To be specific, what connectors are used at the output of the inverter?

Any body who could help me with this question or direct me through the right link, would be very helpful from not only saving me from another telling off by my manger but also giving me the comprehension of the electrical connections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by "the grid", but if it means a "power grid in a city", then the power company should be able to provide you with information on how to connect to the grid as a power provider

Comment: If this inverter is the same project that uses your recent sine wave generator, which was an un-synchronised analog oscillator, and it's meant to be a grid-tied inverter, your manager's concerns may be very valid.

Comment: Have you spoken to your manager about what is required of this connection?

Comment: Having just looked at the manual for my inverter, it uses some unspecified 3-pin power connector, supplied with the inverter.  But that seems such a trivial thing considering the complexity of designing an inverter to connect to the grid supply without something going **bang** spectacularly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by "connectivity" your manager meant data communication for telemetry and control. For example: RS-485, CAN, Ethernet, Bluetooth, GSM etc.

Comment: I doubt it. I'd say the question is about frequency and voltage synchronisation, fault protection, auto shut-off so the lineman doesn't get electrocuted, and how not to power the neighbourhood when the power is switched off.